# Are all cyclic groups considered sub-groups of another group?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups

Consider $Z_5^*$ as a group G, where the group operation is multiplication. Using 2 as a generator and element of G, a cyclic group can be generated:

- 2⋅0 (mod 5) = 0
- 2⋅1 (mod 5) = 2
- 2⋅2 (mod 5) = 4
- 2⋅3 (mod 5) = 1
- 2⋅4 (mod 5) = 3
- 2⋅5 (mod 5) = 0

Is this cyclic group and all cyclic groups that can be generated from $Z_5^*$ considered a sub-group of $Z_5^*$?

Comment: What are you asking here? Are you asking if there's a group $G$ that, given any cyclic group $C$, there is a subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $C$? If so, the answer is "yes", e.g. the unit circle in the complex plane, under multiplication.

Comment: @TheoBendit I edited my question in an attempt to be more specific in what I'm asking.

Comment: Is $0$ an element of $Z_5^*$? If it is, then $Z_5^*$ is not a group, because $0$ has no inverse element.

Comment: Every group is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of some symmetric group. See [Cayley's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is not a cyclic group. Given that the operation in $Z^\ast_5$ is multiplication, what you want is repeated multiplication by 2, i.e. taking powers, which gives you $2^0 =1$, $2^1=2$, $2^2= 4$, $2^3=8\equiv 3$, $2^4=16\equiv 1$.

cyclic groups generated this way are considered subgroups of $Z^\ast_5$. In this instance, the subgroup is the whole group!

Answer (score 2):

As @RyleeLyman pointed out, the list should be denoted as

$$
2^1 = 2 \implies 2 \equiv_{5} 2\\
2^2 = 4 \implies 4 \equiv_{5} 4\\
2^3 = 8 \implies 8 \equiv_{5} 3\\
2^4 = 16 \implies 16 \equiv_{5} 1.\\
$$

The reason being that you are considering the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_{5}^*$.

> Is this cyclic group and all cyclic groups that can be generated from $\mathbb Z_5^*$ considered a sub-group of $\mathbb Z_5^*$?

$\mathbb Z_5^*$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5^*$, since every group $G$ is a subgroup of itself. [[1]](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/rodin/343K/Subgroups.pdf)

Another way of looking at this is to use the fact that all subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic. [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) In other words, the cyclic group that can be formed under the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_5^*$, is $\mathbb Z_5^*$ itself using the generator $2$,

$$
\mathbb Z_5^* = \langle 2 \rangle.
$$